# Найти все комбинации слов по списку букв

Tags: python

Нужно из английского алфавита собрать ВСЕ комбинации слов на определенную длину. Например 4 буквы в слове, нужно собрать все слова по типу. Как это сделать максимально лаконично?

> aaaa aaab aaac ... yyyz yyzz yzzz zzzz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пример:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> print(*combinations('abcd', 2))
('a', 'b') ('a', 'c') ('a', 'd') ('b', 'c') ('b', 'd') ('c', 'd')
```

Если с повторами то:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
>>> print(*combinations_with_replacement('abcd', 2))
('a', 'a') ('a', 'b') ('a', 'c') ('a', 'd') ('b', 'b') ('b', 'c') ('b', 'd') ('c', 'c') ('c', 'd') ('d', 'd')
```

Что бы записать это в файл:

```
In [6]: with open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.txt', mode='a', encoding='utf8') as file:
   ...:     for i in combinations_with_replacement('abcd', 2):
   ...:         file.write(''.join(i) + '\n')
```

Comment: а если нужно записать в тхт, построчно без скобок, запятых и прочего мусора?

Comment: @dimahimma обновил ответ

Comment: работает, но я не понял, почему при print выводится результат в скобках, а при записи в файл- без?

Comment: @dimahimma потому что там есть функция `join()` она берёт все элементы из кортежа, и разделяет их тем что в кавычках, так как в кавычках пусто, образуется строка. Например если сделать так: `','.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])` то получим `'a,b,c'`. Вот примеры: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm

Comment: все понял, спасибо!

Comment: разновидность: [`with open(path, 'w') as file: print(*map(''.join, combinations_with_replacement('abcd', 2)), sep='\n', file=file)`](http://ideone.com/5jLo6g) (режим 'w' (с нуля) в не 'a' (в конец)  и родная кодировка используется)

Answer (score 3):

Если порядок букв в слове имеет значение (если `'ab'` и `'ba'` рассматриваются как разные слова в вашем случае), то чтобы все возможные слова сгенерировать заданной длины из заданного алфавита, можно [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) использовать:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> print(*map(''.join, itertools.product('abc', repeat=2)))
aa ab ac ba bb bc ca cb cc
```